# Localization at a point is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am trying to prove the following result:

> **Proposition 1.** If $A$ is a subring of a field $K$ and $K$ is finitely generated over $A$, then the localization $A_x$ is a field for some $x\in A$.

### My attempts:

This is a consequence(explained below) of the following special case of [Chevalley's theorem](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00FE) for $\operatorname{Spec}(K)\to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$:

> **Theorem 1.** If $A\subset k$ is a subring of a field and the inclusion $i: A\to k$ is finitely presented, then the localization $A_x$ is a field for some $x\in A$.

To see why, note the following elementary lemma

> **Lemma 1.** For any finite type inclusion ring map $A\to k$, there is a non-zero element $x\in A$ such that the ring map $A_x\to k$ is finitely presented.

Refer to [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00FG) for a proof of **Lemma 1.** Basically it says we could invert the leading coefficient of the lowest degree polynomial of an ideal $I\subset A[x]$ to make it principle. Then for any ideal $I\subset A[x_1,...,x_n]$ we could inductively repeat the same process for the $A[x_1,...,x_n]$ case to get the finite number of generators for $I$.

Once we have $x\in A$ above, apply **Theorem 1** to get an element $y\in A$ containing in all non-zero prime ideals $\mathfrak p\not\owns x$, then $xy$ is the element in $A$ contained in all non-zero prime ideals $\mathfrak p\subset A$.

**Theorem 1** gives us the power add an assumption that $A\to k$ is finitely presented. I am trying now to see if I need the full strength of Chevalley's theorem or not. I am looking for a simplified proof of the above special case in **Theorem 1.**.

Comment: Since $A$ is a subring of $K$, it is certainly an integral domain and so we can consider the field of fractions of $A$ inside of $K$. Maybe you can use this to pull off the proof?

By the one, you probably do not want to say "a point" since it makes me think you're taking a localization at a prime ideal.

Comment: Your reasoning "apply Theorem 1 to get an element $y \in A$ containing in all prime ideals $\mathfrak p\not\owns x$" does not make sense. First, you cannot apply Theorem 1 while trying to prove Theorem 1. Second, $A_x$ is a domain, so the intersection of all primes not containing $x$ is $0$, so the only such element $y$ is $0$

Comment: @math54321 I am using Theorem 1 to prove Proposition 1. I should have said "non-zero prime ideals" instead of "prime ideals". I have corrected that in my question.

Comment: OK, thanks for editing, now your question makes sense. I don't think you'll find a much more elementary argument than the one in the answer below. The main step is to show that if $x \in K$ is transcendental over $Q(A)$ then $A \hookrightarrow K$ is not of finite type - once you know this the rest is rather straightforward

Comment: By the way the converse of Proposition 1 is trivially true, so you actually get a characterization of such $A$, i.e. the following are equivalent for a domain $A$: (i) there exists a field $K \supseteq A$ which is a finitely generated $A$-algebra, (ii) there exists a field $K \supseteq A$ which is a finitely presented $A$-algebra, (iii) there exists $x \in A$ such that $A_x$ is a field

Comment: (I should also note that for any domain $A$ and $x \in A$, one has: $A_x$ is a field $\iff A_x = Q(A)$)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe (probably?) there's a simpler proof, but try along the following lines:

- $A$ is an integral domain, so you can form its field of fractions $Q$ within $K$. Prove the case $K=Q$ first.
- Note that since $K/A$ is finitely generated as a ring extension, so is $K/Q$, and hence $K/Q$ is finite (and algebraic) as a field extension (this is not trivial).
- Pick a set of generators of $K/A$ as a ring extension, and consider their matrices w.r.t. a $Q$-basis of $K$. Tweak the generators so that those matrices have entries in $A$, at the cost of a *single* additional generator of the form $\frac{1}{f}$ for $f\in A$.
- Express an arbitrary element of $Q$ in terms of the tweaked generators, and conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Hanno's answer above, I am writing an answer as a special case of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/444471/132430) answer on MO.

Let the embedding $A\hookrightarrow k$ be of finite type, then $\operatorname{Frac}(A)\hookrightarrow k$ will be of finite type as well, and thus finite as a field extension.

Choose generators of $r_1,...,r_n\in k$ over $A$. Since finite extensions are algebraic, $\operatorname{Frac}(A)\hookrightarrow k$ is algebraic, and $r_1,...,r_n$ are zeros of their minimal polynomials $p_i\in\operatorname{Frac}(A)[x]$. Rewrite $p_i(r_i)=0$ as $q_i(r_i)=0$ for some $q_i\in A[x]$ by clearing out the denominator. Then we make $q_i$ monic by inverting the product $f$ of the leading coefficients of all the $q_i$.

$k$ is integral over its subring $A_f$ by the above construction, and we conclude that $A_f$ is a field, as desired.

---

The answer on MO is now more down-to-earth after the author's editing. I suggest reading the answer on MO first before reading mine.

Comment: This is _very_ similar to the answer you already had above.

Comment: Yes I've added that to my answer and useful +1 upvote :)