# Simplified proof of Chevalley's theorem for $A\to k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, ring-homomorphism

I am looking for a simplier proof for the following special case of Chevalley's theorem:

> **Theorem.** If $A\subset k$ is a subring of a field and the inclusion $i: A\to k$ is finitely presented, then $\{(0)\}$ is open in $\operatorname{Spec}(A).$ In other words, there is an element $f\neq 0$ contained in all non-zero prime ideals $\mathfrak p\subset A$.

See [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00FE) for the proof of Chevalley's theorem in general for constructible sets. Are we able to reduce the proof significantly in this case?

Comment: Isn't this a direct consequence of the other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4672282/localization-at-a-point-is-a-field you asked?

Comment: @Hanno Yes. I should have edited the other question instead of asking a new one. I will add this question body to the question you quoted.